# Keras/Tensorflow in Rstudio - Why all these new lines during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, rstudio

Why on earth am I getting all these new lines printed during training on my model with Keras in Rstudio? Can I prevent it somehow? I have another machine running the same model where I don't get these new lines. Running R 3.4.1 on Windows 7

This is the code, I call TestOOS() to start the training

```
library('caret')
library(keras)

neural.train = function(model,XY) 
{
  XY <- as.matrix(XY)
  X <- XY[,-ncol(XY)]
  Y <- XY[,ncol(XY)]
  Y <- ifelse(Y > 0,1,0)

  newModel <- keras_model_sequential() 
  newModel %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 20, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(20)) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 15, activation = 'relu') %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 10, activation = 'relu') %>% 
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu') %>% 
    layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1) %>% 
    layer_activation('sigmoid')

  newModel %>% compile( 
    optimizer = optimizer_sgd(lr = 0.01, momentum = 0, decay = 0, nesterov = FALSE),
    loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
    metrics = c('accuracy')
  )

  newModel %>% fit(X, Y, epochs=100, batch_size=100, validation_split = 0.2)
  Models[[model]] <<- newModel
}

neural.predict = function(model,X) 
{
  if(is.vector(X)) X <- t(X)
  classes <- model %>% predict_classes(X)
  #return(nn.predict(Models[[model]],X))
}

neural.init = function()
{
  set.seed(365)
  Models <<- vector("list")
}

TestOOS = function() 
{
  neural.init()
  XY <<- read.csv('C:/Users/BL-Kyl/Zorro/Data/DeepSignalsEURUSD_L.csv',header = F)
  splits <- nrow(XY)*0.8
  XY.tr <<- head(XY,splits);
  XY.ts <<- tail(XY,-splits)
  neural.train(2,XY.tr)
  X <<- XY.ts[,-ncol(XY.ts)]
  Y <<- XY.ts[,ncol(XY.ts)]
  Y.ob <<- ifelse(Y > 0,1,0)
  Y <<- neural.predict(2,X)
  Y.pr <<- ifelse(Y > 0.5,1,0)
  confusionMatrix(Y.pr,Y.ob)
}
```

And it produces this output

```
Using TensorFlow backend.

Train on 95666 samples, validate on 23917 samples

Epoch 1/100

  8

 15

 2

 2

 3

....

Another 100 lines or so

...

63

64

65

66100/95666 [===================>..........]
 - ETA: 2s - loss: 0.6886 - acc: 0.5411
```

It looks like a new line is printed whenever the first couple of digits are changes for the last two lines

EDIT: Created a gif to show the issue https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3cP0.jpg

Comment: setting `verbose=0`, maybe?

Comment: Didn't help :-(

Comment: If you don't share the code producing these messages, I doubt anyone can help...

Comment: Sorry, you are right of course. I've updated the post with the code

Comment: Any chance you can share a minimally reproducible example? If so, you might want to report it at https://github.com/rstudio/keras.

Comment: Yeah maybe I should. It actually happens even if I just run the sample code from the getting started page.